# server call from client not working

Tags: c#, angularjs, rest

I have a small angularjs application where I'm trying to call a server side function.

I'm not sure but I feel kind a lost when it comes to use the right url for GET/POST from client to server...But I'm not sure the problem is there..

My angular:

```
$http.get({
                method: 'GET',
                url: '/Models/Person/GetTestPersons'
            }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                alert(response);
            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                alert("ErrorCallback");
            });
```

My server function (Models/Person.cs):

```
public static string[] GetTestPersons()
    {
        return new[]
        {
            "Person1",
            "Person2"
        };
    }
```

Now I get to the "alert("ErrorCallback")"

And if I could get this to work.. How do I read the array that is returned?

Error:

> GET http://localhost:51203/Views/[object%20Object] 404 (Not Found)

Comment: So your $http call is erroring? if so what is the error?

Comment: Yes, I end up in errorCallback

Comment: can you post the error you are getting pls

Comment: After `alert("ErrorCallback");`, please add the following line and tell us what you get in the console log: `console.log(response);`

Comment: Please post the server-side code. The response shows a completely different URL from the one you use in your GET. Either you posted the wrong JavaScript snippet, or you are using a redirect in your *server* code to an invalid address.

Comment: What kind of project are you using on the server? From the error message, I suspect it's ASP.NET MVC (the `Views` part).

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Not sure what more you need? I did post my servercode.. the method is inside a class called Person

Comment: @navigator It's quite much information there..What are you interested in? Ex statusText: "Not Found"

Comment: @emptyman this is *not* the server code, it's just a static method on a DTO. Where is your controller, if you are using ASP.NET MVC? Or your web service method if you are using WCF? Where is the code that results in a redirection to `Views`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ought to create a Web API project,
The controller will orchestrate call to your Person model.

A quick starter tutorial is here
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api

Comment: I did read your comment about MVC and Web API. When creating the project I choose an empty project without any references for this..Do I need that? Or should this be able to work anyways ?

Comment: @emptyman you need to *write the Controller code* that retrieves the Person objects and returns them. Simply creating a class with a method doesn't expose it as a REST API

Comment: Hmm I believe I missed a great thing here. I will looked at your link above and believe I need to make some changes ... Thank you